# Using SwingWorker to get realtime result for jtable

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

im tring to update `jTable` row in real time using swing worker.. i wrote some code snippet for that. it given below. My issue is that `jTable` updating only one row. When im debugging, its retrieving one, two or sometimes all the rows. But when im running code sample its retrieving one row. any one can help me for this matter?

```
final DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    removeAllRows(dtm);

    SwingWorker<Void, Object[]> sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Object[]>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Object[] array = null;
            for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<LinkTester.Result>> entrySet : hashMap.entrySet()) {
                boolean foo = true;
                String url = entrySet.getKey();
                ArrayList<LinkTester.Result> results = entrySet.getValue();

                for (LinkTester.Result result : results) {
                    if (foo) {
                        foo = false;
                        publish(new Object[]{url, result.getTestlink(), result.getResponseCode(), result.getAnchortxt()});

                    } else {
                        publish(new Object[]{"", result.getTestlink(), result.getResponseCode(), result.getAnchortxt()});

                    }
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Object[]> chunks) {
            Object[] a = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            dtm.addRow(a);
        }

    };
    sw.execute();
```

Comment: i got answer. its need to add Thread.sleep() :D

Comment: Use `for (Object[] row : chunks) { dtm.addRow(row) }` to make sure you get ALL the results that have been published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `publish`, the values are staged, that is, they aren't immediately passed to `process`, this is done for efficiency reasons

Instead, try using...

```
for (Object[] row : chunks) { 
    dtm.addRow(row) 
}
```

in your `process` method, so you can "process" all the available entries

Now, if you would like the table to be updated more "quickly", you could place a `Thread.sleep(1)` in the `doInBackground` method, which, generally, should allow the `process` method to be called